# How to retrieve last 100 years in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, select

I need to retrieve last 100 years by using a mysql query without using stored functions or temp tables.

Expected result:

- if the current year is 2014, need to select 1914,1915,1916...2014
- if the current year is 2015, need to select 1915,1916,1917...2015

Comment: Please add your table structure. What have you tried so far? What does your query look like?

Answer (score 2):

The challenge is generating integers.  Once you have 100 integers, the rest is easy.  Here is one way:

```
select year(now()) - (d1.n*10 + d2.n) as yr
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0
     ) d1 cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0
     ) d2
order by yr;
```

Comment: This is really good one! I like the way you generated the 100 integers!